# Regex capture price endings .00 and ,00

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, price

I would like to php `preg_match` and remove all price ending but my regex is not working.

For example,

```
1201203,00
123,123.23 
12.23
10.00
10
```

Into

```
1201203
123,123
12
10
10
```

Here is the regex I have so far:

```
[,|.]\d{2}$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is basically correct, although you don't need the `|` in your character set, it should just be `[,.]` (or you could use `(\.|,)`). So you can just use `preg_replace`:

```
$value = preg_replace('/[,.]\d{2}$/', '', $value);
```

For example:

```
$values = array('1201203,00', '123,123.23', '12.23', '10.00', '10');
foreach ($values as &$value) {
    $value = preg_replace('/[,.]\d{2}$/', '', $value);
}
print_r($values);
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1201203
    [1] => 123,123
    [2] => 12
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 10
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Pf8Ti)

Comment: What if I wanted to match all non digits except a decimal or comma 3 characters from the right? Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that would be `[^\d,.]` - that character set represents any character that is *not* (because of the leading `^`) a digit, `,` or `.`

Comment: but only if its the 3rd character from the right. Because 1,000,000.00 has commas and decimals. I need 1000000.00

Comment: Presuming you want the last two characters to be digits you would use `[^\d,.]\d{2}$`